# Bind focus to datacontext in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, focus

I would like to bind the current focus to the datacontext. My menu system has a viewmodel that contains a list of ButtonViewModels as datacontext. How would I go about having the focused button be determined by the datacontext?

There is a FocusManager.FocusedElement, but this references to a control and the idea of a ViewModel is to not depend on the implementation of the View...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to place a DataTrigger in the `Button` Style which binds to a property called `IsFocused` in the `ButtonViewModel` and in the Setter Bind `FocusManager.FocusedElement` to the Button where IsFocused is set to true. This should allow you to Control the Focus directly from the `ButtonViewModel`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusBindingStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Test" Style="{StaticResource FocusBindingStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it will only work once for some reason. Also the binding only works 1 way. I want the IsFocused property to update based on the currently focused item.

Comment: Okay, after I added handlers to the GotFocus and LostFocus events to set the IsFocused property it works. Thanks!